# How to add row top and bottom margins to asp.net gridview?

Tags: css, asp.net, gridview

There aren't any attributes like CellPadding or CellSpacing that will accomplish this for me and when I try to add css to the grid tr's to change the top and bottom margins, they are ignored. How do I add a little bit of spacing between each generated row from the gridview?

Comment: First: could you provide some sample code, so we can see what you're working with? Second: Try setting a `GridView.ItemTemplate` > `ItemTemplate.Style` within your `GridView`, applying padding or margin to the `GridViewItem` that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Margin doesn't work on `table` elements, use `padding`, or like in below sample, set a top and/or bottom border on your `tr`

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}
td {
  background: gray;
}
tr {
  border: 0px solid white;
  border-width: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Hello there
    </td>  
  </tr>  
  <tr>
    <td>
      Hello there
    </td>  
  </tr>  
  <tr>
    <td>
      Hello there
    </td>  
  </tr>  
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this using

```
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 0 10px;
```

Snippet

```css
table.grey-theme {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0 10px;
  margin: 50px;
}

table.grey-theme td {
  border: solid #777 1px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table class="grey-theme">
  <tr>
    <td>Dogs</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cats</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Parrots</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Use it in `asp:GridView` like

```
<asp:GridView ID="PetGrid" runat="server" CssClass="grey-theme">
```